# boost.build Vs boost.python

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-build

Context -- Trying to use Boost.Python set of C++ libraries to interface with C++ code.
Main idea is to test C++ code (.so files) by using them like python from a QA point of view.

Questions now;

1. BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE wrapper, do we really need to include in every .cpp to be interfaced from Python? Say we have test.cpp, can't we have Boost wrapper written test_qa.cpp so that actual dev code is not changed in the process?
2. Looked Boost.org site to get more clarity, what is the difference between Boost.Build and Boost.Python?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Boost Build documentation](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/):

> Boost.Build is an easy way to build C++ projects, everywhere.

From the [Boost Python documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/index.html):

> ... a C++ library which enables seamless interoperability between C++ and the Python programming language

I would say the difference between these two parts of Boost should be pretty obvious.